# How to list content of directory into spinner?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am attempting to obtain all of the files inside of a directory and display them inside of a spinner. I am trying to use the code below but can't figure out how to display it inside of the spinner.

```
File("sdcard/Velocity").walkTopDown().forEach { println(it) }
```

Comment: In that case, I recommend you look at the basic Spinner tutorial provided by Android here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner

Answer (score 2):

To get the files as

```
public String[] getFiles(String path) {

 File directory = new File(path);
 File[] files = directory.listFiles();
 String arr[] = new String[files.length];
 for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  fileList[i] = files[i].getName();
 }
}
```

To show the in activity

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

To populate

```
public class SpinnerExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] arraySpinner = getFiles();
        Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```